# Where to initiate ImagePickerController in a ViewController

Tags: iphone, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am using the following to push my cameraViewController

```
[appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:cameraViewController animated:YES];
```

In my cameraViewController's ViewDidLoad i use the following to start imagepicker

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

When I DismissModalViewController and pop the cameraViewController, I get back to my main menu successfully. The problem is that when I push cameraViewController again, I get a blank screen, This is probably because presentModalViewController is not called again. I have tried to put presentModalViewController at various places, like init and loadview, but none have worked for me.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

What I am try to implement is a back button on my overlay to go back to main menu if and when desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add imagePickerController as a subview to your cameraViewController instead of presenting it modally (note that then you have to call `[imagePickerController viewWillAppear:YES];` and `[imagePickerController viewDidAppear:YES];` manually).

Or just move your `[self presentModalViewController:self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES];` method to `viewWillAppear:` (this gets called by navigation controller).